# How to specify parameters in box-view API header?

Tags: box-view-api

I am using the following piece of C# code to upload, convert and download a .pptx file, via Box view API.

```
        var boxViewID = "";
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        String url_ = @"https://upload.view-api.box.com/1/documents";
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Headers.Add("Authorization:Token " + "MY_CODE"/*Configuration.BoxViewAPIKey*/);
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        wr.Timeout = 1000000;            
        wr.SendChunked = true;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        Exception exc = null;
        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
        try
        {
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; non_svg=\"true\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
            string header = string.Format(headerTemplate,"file", file, contentType);
            Console.WriteLine(header);
            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[40960];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            int totalSent = 0;
            int totalLength = (int)fileStream.Length;

            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                totalSent += bytesRead;
                var percent = new decimal(100.0 * totalSent / totalLength);
                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress("Box processing", percent);
                }
                rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            exc = ex;
        }
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        int seconds = (int)(end - start).TotalSeconds;
        if(seconds>=0)
        {
            if(exc!=null)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }
        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            var res = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            var docRes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(res);
            if (docRes["id"] != null)
                boxViewID = docRes["id"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }
        return boxViewID;
```

Specifying "non_svg" parameter should create .png images for every slide in the presentation (instead of .svg + .html pairs). However, the API seems to ignore this part of the request and I am always getting svg files. 
Any idea on what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `non_svg` option causes PNG representations to be generated for each page, but the SVG representation is still generated. The viewer will only load the PNG files if SVG is not supported in the browser (basically only IE 8). Try changing page-1.svg to page-1.png in the browser (e.g., https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions/465c5d45caf04752a6113b0e5df593a5/assets/page-1.png vs https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions/465c5d45caf04752a6113b0e5df593a5/assets/page-1.svg). All of the assets will exist in content.zip if you use the documents [content](https://developers.box.com/view/#get-documents-id-content) endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Basically this means that I can't get just a set of .png images inside content.zip file? This conversion .svg to .png is done inside the Box viewer?

Comment: You get both the .png and .svg files if you specify `non_svg`. You always get .svg files regardless.